# How to listen to Object instantiation events in Java

Tags: java, cdi, instantiation

I am building a Java SE application heavily dependent on JaxB and Weld, the two being designed quite differently are inherently non compatible. To illustrate, the logger below will be null after unmarshalling.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class MyObject {
    @Inject
    private Logger log;
}
```

Using an `UnmarshallListener` I am doing Weld injection on an existing Object instance using the `BeanManager`.

Really I use CDI on all objects within my program. I could equally perform the same injection on any instance using a factory method but that would require (a lot of) refactoring.

I am wondering if there is any way to override the instantiation of evey Object in my code by overrideing the

```
Object o = new Object(); // Catch this event and perform CDI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah sure , you can catch object instantiations with an [Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html). The agent needs to register a [ClassFileTransformer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) that will scan the bytecode of all loaded classes for **new object** instructions and do well.. what you need it to do.

Check out [this tutorial](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-instrumentation/) for an example on how to use the instrumentation packages.